# Adding Accept header in Spring

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, resttemplate, spring-rest

I'm trying to consume a JSON object from http://www.foaas.com/ in my Spring RESTful app. However they require content negotiation with an Accept header.

I have tried this method found here on SO:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", "application/json");

HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

HttpEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(foaasURI, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

I'm getting 403 forbidden at every attempt.

Using Postman for adding an Accept header works fine so I know everything is correct on foaas end. How do I proceed?

Comment: `ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://foaas.com/off/Tom/Everyone?shoutcloud&i18n=de", HttpMethod.GET, null, Object.class);`it's working OK for me. Could you post the URL that you're trying to access? Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Im using Spring 4.0.0. Even with your example I am getting 403 forbidden. Which is weird since foaas is completely open.

Comment: I'm taking a look at my testing code and I have notice that it's working because I'm using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory instead SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory. Let me take a look inwards to figure what really happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is NOT with the `"application/json"` header. Your current code is successfully adding the `"application/json"` header.

The server is rejecting your request because of some authentication issues.

> A 403 response generally indicates one of two conditions:
>
> Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not
>   permitted to perform the requested operation.

Please refer this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpHeaders#setAccept`

```
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should specify a user agent header in the request for foass.com.

```
headers.set("User-Agent", "eltabo");
```

RestTemplate default requestfactory (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) does not specify any user-agent for its requets.

Hope it helps.